# Common way to format Exception

Tags: python, python-3.x

The standard format of an exception (like it is printed by the default `sys.excepthook`) is something like

```
"%s: %s" % (type(e).__name__, e)
```

However, that seems error-prone to me. For example, what if `__name__` is not defined?

Is there some standard way? I looked into the `traceback` module and it seems to handle quite a few special cases.

Comment: How could the type's name not be defined?

Comment: Types always have a name. A much bigger danger of trying to do it this way would be the fact that `type(e)` is the wrong thing for old-style classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard way is to use `traceback.format_exception_only`. If you want custom formatting etc. you can copy the logic from there and modify it (e.g. IPython does this).

Answer (score 0):

I used this code to catch and log all errors, hope it will be usefull for you

```
import traceback
def my_handler(exctype, value, tb):
    logger.error(''.join(traceback.format_tb(tb))+
                 '{0}: {1}'.format(exctype.__name__, value))

sys.excepthook = my_handler
```

`__name__` is a buid-in property, so each class gonna have it